# TextField data disappears after tableview.reload ()

Tags: ios, uitextfield, tableview, swift4

I have a table view which has a textfield(added programmatically) in the cell. I am using editActionsForRowAt method to insert and delete cells, however every time I insert/delete, the textfield data that I entered previously disappears. I think because tableview.reload method.
Can you please advice?

Thanks a lot!

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let myAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "INSERT") { (action, indexPath) in

        print("I'm here")

      self.data[indexPath.section].subType.insert("Set", at: indexPath.item)
     //   self.data[indexPath.section].subType.insert("Set", at: indexPath.section)
        print("inserttt")
        self.tblView.reloadData();

    }

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
       // if editingStyle == .delete{
            print("delete")

            self.data[indexPath.section].subType.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tblView.reloadData()

       // }
    }

  //  tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    return [myAction,delete]
}






    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cells")
  //  cell?.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.section].subType[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.section].headerName



    var sampleTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 180, y: 10, width: 60, height: 40))
    sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
    sampleTextField.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9027962089, green: 0.781386435, blue: 0.9435198903, alpha: 1)
    sampleTextField.tag=indexPath.item
    //use this if you want to clear test when you edit again
  //  sampleTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
    sampleTextField.placeholder=data[indexPath.section].headerName
    headerSection=data[indexPath.section].headerName!
    cell?.addSubview(sampleTextField)

    sampleTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UITextFieldDelegate.textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidEnd)





    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Cells are reused and `cellForRowAt` is called once for each row. Your code adds always a new text field without checking if there is already one. It's highly recommended to create a **custom** cell with text field in Interface Builder and you have to save the text field content changes in the data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the text that you want, and in cellForRowAt just add it to the text field.